# Embed youku video on HTTPS site

Tags: ssl, https, embed, mixed-content

I am trying to embed videos from http://youku.com on a website served via HTTPS. Unfortunately they only support HTTP at the moment.

Any ideas?

Regards,

Comment: I think this depends on the browser. Supposedly [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/MixedContent#Mixed_passive.2Fdisplay_content) will allow passive content (video, audio, images). Chrome seems to require the user to click a button.

Comment: So, you mean it is all up to the user to enable mixed content in some browsers. What a pitty for UX. Thx,

Answer (score 2):

If you're referencing it via the player API e.g. http://player.youku.com/jsapi you can use https://players.youku.com/jsapi

Comment: Does this actually let you get an https path for an embedded player?